# Create a custom annotation to validate userToken from header

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop, spring-annotations

I am trying to create an independent packageable jar with a custom annotation, which on inclusion in a controller mapping function (and taking userToken as input in header), returns a boolean whether the user is authenticated or now.

```
// Expected way of inclusion
public @ResponseBody boolean isAuthenticated(@Authenticator(@RequestHeader("userToken")) Boolean isUserAuthenticated) {
return isUserAuthenticated;
}
```

I know that this won't be the right syntax, since using this code gives the error that RequestMapping cannot be converted to String (and annotations only accept primitive values).

I am also open to other approaches, but it should have the flexibility to return authentication boolean only when needed and not through global interception.

**Important**: Please note @Authenticator comes from an independent package, imported in the current package through Maven. Would HTTPServletRequest pass in ConstraintValidator.

Comment: I think you you're trying to rewrite Spring Security.

Comment: Please mention which module of Spring security can be reused here. Plus, I wanted a light package so I didn't include too many dependencies.

Comment: I've added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the spring security BasicAuthenticationFilter :

```
public class MyBasicAuthenticationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {

    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public MyBasicAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        super(authenticationManager);
        this.authenticationManager=authenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // do you checks here
        super.doFilterInternal(request, response, chain);
    }
}
```

Then add this to your security config with something like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();

        http.addFilterBefore(new MyBasicAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager());
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
        return new MyAuthenticationManager();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this is what I need. Please note that my package will be included in other projects and Annotation should simply accept the userToken and validate it, and throw error if there are issues.